# Failed to execute 'appendBuffer' on 'SourceBuffer': This SourceBuffer has been removed from the parent media source

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom, html5-video

My goal here is to continuously render a video blob `e.data` into the video element e.g. continuous playback.

The code below throws:

```
DOMException: Failed to execute 'appendBuffer' on 'SourceBuffer': This SourceBuffer has been removed from the parent media source.
```

What could be wrong in this code?

```
    var options = {mimeType: 'video/webm'};
    var mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, options);
    var player = document.querySelector("#player");

    var mediaSource = new MediaSource();
    player.src = URL.createObjectURL(mediaSource);
    mediaSource.addEventListener('sourceopen', sourceOpen, {once: true})

    function sourceOpen() {
        //URL.revokeObjectURL(player.src);
        var sourceBuffer = mediaSource.addSourceBuffer('video/webm; codecs="vorbis,vp8"');
        mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function(e) {
            console.log("Data available")
            if (e.data.size > 0) {
                var bufferPromise = e.data.arrayBuffer();
                bufferPromise.then(function(array){
                    sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(array);
                })
            }
        }
    }
```

Update: This is solved by `sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(new Uint8Array(array));` however the code still is not functional with Chrome, it only works with Firefox.